# Encryption and Decryption with ASE-124

Tags: java

key: 584E9FAFE4F37A32D9FAF82A0954C20A 
by using ASE-124 algorithm provide the Encryption and Decryption
i try with the following code but its not working with this key.

```
 public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception 
{
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        chiper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = chiper.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception 
{
    // generate key 
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    chiper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new     BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText);
    byte[] decValue = chiper.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is a weak statement. How does it not work? Does it compile? Does it run without any errors? No? Which errors are thrown? Does it work, just the output is unexpected? Please, provide a sample expected input/output. Does it work differently with different keys?

Answer (score -2):

```
// Performs Encryption
public static String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception 
{
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        chiper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = chiper.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
}

// Performs decryption
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception 
{
        // generate key 
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher chiper = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        chiper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedText);
        byte[] decValue = chiper.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
}
```

//generateKey() is used to generate a secret key for AES algorithm

```
enter code here private static Key generateKey() throws Exception 
{
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algorithm);
        return key;
}

// performs encryption & decryption 
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
        String plainText = "1234";
        String encryptedText = LoginAuthentication.encrypt(plainText);
        String decryptedText = LoginAuthentication.decrypt(encryptedText);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + plainText);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + encryptedText);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + decryptedText);
}
```

}